# Question about the operator norm on $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, operator-theory

So here is my question,

I have to decide whether the following statement is true

Let $T$ be an isomorphism on $\mathbb R^2$. Then 
$$\|T\|=\frac{1}{\|T^{-1}\|}$$

I am pretty sure that the statement is false. Let T be an invertible operator of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then the following disproves the claim:
\begin{align*}
\|T\| &:= \sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{\|T(x)\|}{\|x\|} \\
&= \sup_{y \neq 0} \frac{\|y\|}{\|T^{-1}(y)\|} \\
&= \sup_{y \neq 0} \frac{1}{\frac{\|T^{-1}(y)\|}{\|y\|}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\inf_{y \neq 0}\frac{\|T^{-1}(y\|}{\|y\|}} \\
&\neq \frac{1}{\|T^{-1}\|}
\end{align*}

Comment: What you have done is prove that $\frac{1}{\|T\|}$ equals the smallest expansion factor for $T^{-1}$. That's quite nice, and certainly suggests that usually $\|T^{-1}\| \neq \frac{1}{\|T\|}$ but, to really prove they aren't equal, you should give an explicit example, like Berci has done below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, let $T:=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&2}$ then $\|T\|=2$ and $\|T^{-1}\|=1$.